# Strcmp Error in Binary Search Tree Insertion (Recursion)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, insert, binary-tree

i'm trying to implement some functions that allow me to add "Books" to a binary search tree for the "Student" class, but I'm getting a strange error:

**msvcr100d.dll!strcmp(unsigned char * str1, unsigned char * str2)  Line 83 Asm**

The program is entirely in C/C++, so I'm not sure why its returning an assembly language error? My first thought is something is wrong with my use of strcmp, and the Call Stack shows Line 188 as the last executed statement (before the above error), which means I'm probably messing up my recursion somewhere. I am calling the insertBook() function of "Student", so here is my "Student" class. Any help? Thanks.

```
class Student : public Personnel { //inherit from Personnel
public:
    Book *bookTree;

    Book* searchBookTree(Book *bookNode, char *title) {
        if ((strcmp(title, bookNode->title)) < 0) //***LINE 188
            return searchBookTree(bookNode->left, title); 

        else if ((strcmp(title, bookNode->title)) > 0)
            return searchBookTree(bookNode->right, title);

        else
            return bookNode;
    }

    void insertBook(Book *node) {
        Book *newBook, *parent;
        newBook = node;

        newBook->left = NULL;
        newBook->right = NULL;

        if (bookTree == NULL) { //if bookTree is empty
            bookTree = newBook; 
        }
        else {          
            parent = searchBookTree(bookTree, newBook->title);
            newBook->left = parent->left;
            newBook->right = parent->right;
        }   
    }

    void printBooks(Book *top) {
        Book *root = top;
        if (root != NULL) {
            printBooks(root->left);
            cout << "BOOK LIST" << endl;
            cout << "Title:\t\t" << root->title << endl;
            cout << "URL:\t\t" << root->url << endl;
            printBooks(root->right);
        }
    } 

    void display() {
            Personnel::display();
            cout << "STUDENT" << endl;  
            cout << "Level:\t\t" << getLevel() << endl;
            printBooks(bookTree); cout << endl;
    }

    Student(char *cName, char *cBirthday, char *cAddress, char *cPhone, char *cEmail, level gradeLevel) 
        : Personnel(cName, cBirthday, cAddress, cPhone, cEmail) 
    {
        bookTree = NULL;
        setLevel(gradeLevel);
    }
```

};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Book* searchBookTree(Book *bookNode, char *title) {
        if ((strcmp(title, bookNode->title)) < 0) //***LINE 188
            // What happens if bookNode->left == NULL ???
            return searchBookTree(bookNode->left, title); 

        else if ((strcmp(title, bookNode->title)) > 0)
            // What happens if bookNode->right== NULL ???
            return searchBookTree(bookNode->right, title);

        else
            return bookNode;
    }
```

you'll need a termination point in your search function. At the top, I'd first check if bookNode == NULL.

Answer (score 1):

Your recursive search an important termination test missing! At some point, you hit the bottom of the tree without finding the item. And so your search function is called with a null pointer for the tree node! The problem is not in `strcmp`, but in the null pointer in one of the argument expressions.

You have only considered the case when the item exists in the tree and is eventually found, neglecting the not-found case.

*Programmers are not to be measured by their ingenuity and their logic but by the completeness of their case analysis.*

- Alan J. Perlis, Epigram #32

Comment: Is that not covered by the 'else { return bookNode; }' function in searchBookTree()?

Comment: That else clause handles two cases: when you have found the node, but also when you have not found anything. Problem is when you have not found anything, `bookNode` is a null pointer. And the problem is that prior to reaching that `else`, that pointer has been dereferenced. You don't check for it being null on entry into the function.

Comment: Ask yourself, what if the tree is completely empty, i.e. a null pointer? What should the function do if given such a tree?   That case happens even when the entire tree as such is not empty, because a leaf node's left and right pointers are such empty trees and the recursion reaches leaf nodes.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the help. If its given a null pointer (such as the end of a node's leaf), then I should return the parent of that null entry, correct?

Comment: You do not have the parent of the null entry because a null pointer cannot be used to find the parent, and in the case when the tree is empty, there in fact is no such parent. I believe that the right thing in your program is just to return null if the search function encounters an empty tree. The null return value will indicate "not found". (The caller has to test for null, obviously.)

Comment: Ah I see, you are using the search routine inside your insert routine to find the place where to insert.  I would recommend against that. It's easy to have the insert routine itself be recursive, similar to the search routine. Keep the public `insertBook` routine but make an `insertBookHelper` which is recursive. `insertBookHelper` can stick the node into the tree and return the new tree. `insertBook` just does this: `{ bookTree = insertBookHelper(node); }`

Answer (score 0):

Your `insert` routine has problems. I suggest you make your `searchBookTree` just return a null pointer when it doesn't find anything. Do not use that routine in the implementation of `insertBook`. Rather, you can write `insertBook` recursively also:

```
private:
    // Inserts bookNode into tree, returning new tree:

    Book *insertBookHelper(Book *tree, Book *bookNode) {
        if (tree == NULL)
            return bookNode; // bookNode becomes new tree

        // no need to call strcmp twice!!!
        int cmp = strcmp(title, bookNode->title);

        if (cmp < 0) {
            tree->left = insertBookHelper(tree->left, bookNode->title); 
        else if (cmp > 0)
            tree->right = insertBookHelper(tree->right, bookNode->title);
        else {
            // Uh oh! Tree already contains that title, what to do?
            // Answer: update!
            // I don't know how to write this because I don't know
            // how your Book class handles the memory for the strings,
            // and what other members it has besides the title.
            // this could be a possibility:
            // bookNode->left = tree->left;    // install same child pointers
            // bookNode->right = tree->right;  // into bookNode.
            // *tree = *bookNode; // if Book has a sane copy constructor!!!
        }
        return tree;
    }

 public:
    void insertBook(Book *node) {
        tree = insertBookHelper(tree, node);
    }
```

Do you see how the recursion works? It's a little different from the pure search. Each recursive level handles the insertion into the subtree and returns the new subtree. Often, the returned tree is exactly the same as the tree that went in! But when inserting into an empty tree, the returned tree is not the same: the tree that went in is a null pointer, but a non-null pointer comes out. This trick of pretending that we are making a new tree and returning it as a replacement for the old tree makes for smooth code.

Comment: You should not be using raw C strings (`char *`) in C++ code. It is error prone and counter-productive. Unless the exercise is how to manage low-level memory. Use `std::string` from the `<string>` header. The strings can be assigned, passed and returned, without worries about bad pointers or memory leaks.